# How to use VContainer to inject dependencies across assembly definitions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've set my project up so that my games presentation and simulation code are in separate assemblies, and would like to use VContainer to inject dependencies across them when needed (the presentation layer has an assembly definition reference to the simulation layer, but the simulation layer doesn't have one to the presentation for context here). I currently have 2 lifetime scopes, `SimulationLifetimeScope` and `PresentationLifetimeScope`, which live on the same parent object in the scene and are both set to auto run.

When running the game, the `PresentaionLifetimeScope` errors out due to trying to `[Inject]` a player controller script that lives in the simulation layer and is registered inside the `SimulationLifetimeScope` into a presentation script, saying that there is no such registration of that type.

How would I set up the `LifetimeScope`'s in a way that allows access across assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

`LifetimeScope` must be placed in a layer that has access to all layers. Below is an example of [Assembly definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) division.

create a DI layer
[image]

It may be placed on the Domain layer.

[image]

BTW: My [SMCP](https://github.com/IShix-g/SMCPxPuzzleGame) architecture uses VContainer, which may be helpful.

**Edit: Dependencies**

**When a DI layer is added:**

[image]

**When a Domain.DI layer is added:**

Dependencies on the Domain layer are omitted.

[image]

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, thanks for the example too! 

I was hoping to avoid having too many dependencies between the assemblies though, doing it this way would mean that the DI assembly needs a reference to both the simulation and presentation layers, as well as the simulation and presentation having a reference to the DI. Would there be a way to have things stored or accessible in the top DI layer, or maybe using the `EntryPoint` class as a go between instead?

Comment: If `SimulationLifetimeScope` and `PresentationLifetimeScope` are placed in the DI layer, would you still get the same reply? (see screenshot)

Comment: Dependencies was added to the answer.